# Case statement if string contains

Tags: excel, vba, case, contains

I am trying to do a select case statement where its based off a string that I have stored in a variable contains certain words. From what I've seen everywhere I've looked I have it right, but its not working. I keep getting "Compile Error: Invalid Qualifier" on my variable "Model", in the case statement, i.e Case Model.Contains("GR CHER").

Does anyone see something that Im missing here?

```
i = 2
Model = Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 8)

While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
    Select Case True
        Case Model.Contains("GR CHER")
            Model = "Grand Cherokee"
        Case Model.Contains("CHRGR")
            Model = "Charger"
        Case Model.Contains("HLLCT")
            Model = "HellCat"
        Case Model.Contains("R1500")
            Model = "Ram 1500"
        Case Else
            Rows([i]).EntireRow.Delete
            i = i - 1
    End Select

    Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 8).Value = Model

    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Comment: so you are treating Model as text variable and so you would want to use something like this instead. `Instr("GR CHER", Model)`

Comment: why are you evaluating Model only to discard it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't look like VBA.

Also, I don't think you can do anything that equals "contains" is a `Select Case`

Your code, refactored, also fixing a few other issues

```
Sub zx()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Model As Variant
    Dim Deleted As Boolean
    i = 2

    With Sheets("Data")
        Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1))
            Model = Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 8)
            Deleted = False
            If Model Like "*GR CHER*" Then
                Model = "Grand Cherokee"
            ElseIf Model Like "*CHRGR*" Then
                Model = "Charger"
            ElseIf Model Like "*HLLCT*" Then
                Model = "HellCat"
            ElseIf Model Like "*R1500*" Then
                Model = "Ram 1500"
            Else
                Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                Deleted = True
            End If
            If Not Deleted Then
                .Cells(i, 8).Value = Model
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: for some reason it executes the else statement on every row (deletes every row after the header row), even when the values its looking for are there. Even when I step through it and look at the value for Model,it will be, for example, GR CHER but the code will delete the row anyway.

Comment: Works fine for me. look closely at spelling and check for special characters eg nbs

Comment: it looks like what its doing is looking for exact matches. If i have "AVENGER (3.6L)" in a cell, and the code says
    ElseIf Model Like "*AVENGER*" Then
                    Model = "Avenger"
                    Deleted = False
it wont catch on that elseif statement and will go down until the else and delete the row

Comment: If you want case insensitive use `Model = UCase( ... )` and write your If clauses in CAPS.  To allow for partial matches include the `*`'s as shown in my answer

Comment: that was it. the values in the cells are all upper case, I didnt even think about the fact that I wrote the value it was looking for in standard capitalization i.e Grand Cherokee. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

No need to

1. Loop through each row to delete - quicker to `AutoFilter`
2. Or derive and store the variable *Model* at each step as you don`t use it

You could try the approach below, which is the `VBA` equivalent

- of entering a formula in a working column to retun TRUE or FALSE for testing each string in column H
- filtering out the *False* results

*`=COUNT(SEARCH({"*GR CHER*","*CHRGR*","*HLLC*","*R1500*"},I2))=1`*

*code*

```
Sub QuickCull()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Sheets("Data")
Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.[b2], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With rng1.Offset(0, 1)
     .EntireColumn.Insert
     .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNT(SEARCH({""*GR CHER*"",""*CHRGR*"",""*HLLC*"",""*R1500*""},RC[5]))=1"
     .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="False"
     .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
     .EntireColumn.Delete
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned, you can't use "contains", the function would be "InStr" but I am pretty sure the following method will get the work done.

```
Sub Models()
    Dim i As Long: i = 2
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        While i <= .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(i, 8) Like "*GR CHER*" Then
                .Cells(i, 8) = "Grand Cherokee"
                i = i + 1
            ElseIf .Cells(i, 8) Like "*CHRGR*" Then
                .Cells(i, 8) = "Charger"
                i = i + 1
            ElseIf .Cells(i, 8) Like "*HLLCT*" Then
                .Cells(i, 8) = "HellCat"
                i = i + 1
            ElseIf .Cells(i, 8) Like "*R1500*" Then
                .Cells(i, 8) = "Ram 1500"
                i = i + 1
            Else
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what its doing is looking for exact matches. If i have
 "AVENGER (3.6L)" in a cell
and the code says:

```
If Model Like "*AVENGER*" Then 
    Model = "Avenger"
    Deleted = False
```

or if i try:

```
If Model Like "AVENGER" Then 
    Model = "Avenger"
    Deleted = False
```

it wont catch on that If statement and will go down until the else statement and delete the row